# Jquery to display the list items in a content editor webpart

Tags: 2010, jquery

Hi Am using sharepoint 2010 and am trying to find ways to display the list items in a content editor webpart using jquery . I want to display them i a html table. Let me know any kind of suggestions on this. Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what context you want to use, but look at http://spservices.codeplex.com

Comment: Tested ,works fine : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/544538/JQuery-with-SharePoint-2010

Comment: HI Nikil thanks for the link that has done my work.. I got the list items to the table using jquery now I have small issue one of the column data am pulling to table is link how would I retrieve it as same using jquery into the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SP Services to display your data from list in table format
You can download spservices from  [SpServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/).

In Below Example I am having table strcture:

Request Status
Request Title
Request Created
Request Owner
Course Deployment Date

and append the pulled data to table using below code:

```
var query = '<Query>'+
                '<Where>'+
                    '<And>'+
                        '<Eq>'+
                            '<FieldRef Name="NewItemActivation"/><Value Type="Text">Yes</Value>'+
                        '</Eq>'+
                        '<Neq>'+
                            '<FieldRef Name="IsOldRequest"/><Value Type="Text">Y</Value></Neq>'+
                    '</And>'+
                '</Where>'+
            '</Query>';

var view = '<ViewFields>'+
            '<FieldRef Name="TrainingTitle" />'+
            '<FieldRef Name="RequestStatus" />'+
            '<FieldRef Name="Created" />'+
            '<FieldRef Name="RequestorName" />'+
            '<FieldRef Name="DeployementDate" />'+
          '</ViewFields>';
var htmlTable='';
var TrainingTitle;
var RequestStatus;
var Created;
var RequestorName;
var Deployement;
  $().SPServices({
                operation: "GetListItems",
                async: false,
                listName: "TrainTrax",
                CAMLViewFields: view ,
                CAMLQuery : query ,
                completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                    var totalRows = parseInt($(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("rs:data").attr("ItemCount"));

                    if(totalRows > 0)
                    {                       
                        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode('z:row').each(function()
                        {
                            TrainingTitle = $(this).attr("ows_TrainingTitle");
                            if(TrainingTitle === undefined)
                                TrainingTitle = '';

                            RequestStatus = $(this).attr("ows_RequestStatus");
                            if(RequestStatus === undefined)
                                RequestStatus ='';

                            Created = $(this).attr("ows_Created");
                            if(Created === undefined)
                                Created ='';

                            RequestorName = $(this).attr("ows_RequestorName");
                            if(RequestorName === undefined)
                                RequestorName= '';

                            Deployement = $(this).attr("DeployementDate");
                            if(Deployement === undefined)
                                Deployement ='';
            // Store data in variable once all data in stored append it to table                    
                            htmlTable+="<tr><td>"+RequestStatus +"</td><td>"+TrainingTitle +"</td><td>"+Created+"</td><td>"
                                        +RequestorName +"</td><td>"+ Deployement +"</td></tr>";                                 
                        });

                        $("#exportToExcel").append(htmlTable);

                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 5):

For the situation you're describing, I like using Knockout and the REST API or the SharePoint JavaScript Object Model.

Here is a basic example that takes 10 users from the user information list (which is just a hidden list on all 2010 sites) using the REST API, and displays them in an HTML table -- below is the entire source for a content editor to do so (I usually put it in a seperate text file in an asset library, then point the content editor 'source' to it):

```
<div id="userTable">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Account Name</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: users">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: account"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
    'use strict';
    var simpleDemo = simpleDemo || {};

    // setup the View-Model we'll use to manage the page
    simpleDemo.ViewModel = function() {
        // definitions
        var self = this;
        self.users = ko.observableArray();

        function UserInfoItem(account, firstName, lastName) {
            this.account = account;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        self.initAsync = function() {
            return $.getJSON("/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList?$top=10", function (data) {
                var userArray = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    userArray.push(new UserInfoItem(
                        data.d[i].Account,
                        data.d[i].FirstName,
                        data.d[i].LastName
                    ));
                }
                self.users(userArray);
            });
        }

        // viewModel setup
        self.initAsync();

    };

    // this immediately executed function will create our view model and apply the 
    // HTML value bindings as soon as our content editor loads
    (function() {
        ko.applyBindings(new simpleDemo.ViewModel());
    })()
</script>
```

Note that some of the users you get may not have first and last names if they are system accounts!

You can find a lot more information about the different options/technologies out there on the web:

- SharePoint 2010 REST API:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx
- SharePoint 2010 JavaScript Object Model (JSOM): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185015(v=office.14).aspx
- Knockout: http://knockoutjs.com/

You could also use Angular, or Ember to provide the same functionality that Knockout does here, but I tend to like Knockout's syntax (although I like Angular's just as much) and it's much lighter-weight than Angular or Ember as well. You could also use just jQuery to dynamically build a table from your JSON results, but I find that object binding and dependency tracking of the other frameworks make that approach seem a bit old fashioned! Your specific technique is a decision you should research and make yourself though. Good luck!

Comment: +1 That is really good answer that demonstrates how to utilize Knockout, jQuery and the SharePoint REST

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this would not to use jQuery. You should be able to do this by doing either of these:

1. Use a list web part of your list with a custom view and use the styles that come with SP.

or

2. Create a data view of your list.  You can modify that to look exactly how you want it pretty easily.